# Angular directive based on other directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-bootstrap

In my current project we're using angular and ui.bootstrap as UI library. What I'm trying to do:

- to make dropdown with matches for typeahead element to have the same width as input field

How I'm trying to achieve that:

- I'm trying to create an attribute directive which is going to add an typeahead-template-url attribute to typeahead element.

What problem I have faced:

- after directive is rendered element has new attribute set, but it doesn't take effect

Am I working in a right direction? Is there some other solution for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like the right way, try and see if it works. If it doesn't work add the code of the directive you wrote.

Comment: Hard to grasp the problem without code and a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, guys! Here's the idea of what I am doing [in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/suy22C2btg6eEHrDBjLd?p=preview) There're two input elements with uib-typeahead directive. One is using typeahead template defined directly in HTML, second is trying to set template programmatically which does not work.